# Xcode: Communication with apple failed, No profiles for xxxxxx found

Tags: xcode, react-native, app-store, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbkLq.jpg)

I tried to archive the app on Xcode, but I got the error like this.

I need to submit the app on the app store, due to this reason I can't able to do that. I tried to change the bundle identifier, created new profile still getting the same error.